# Pass data from VueJS Plugin to VueJS Component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm creating a loading bar plugin for VueJS and I want to control data of a VueJS component (part of the plugin) with the plugin.

So, in the end I want to do the following:

Include plugin in main.js

```
import VueLoadingBar from 'path-to-plugin';

Vue.use(VueLoadingBar);
```

Include plugin component in App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-loading-bar><vue-loading-bar>
  </div>
</template>
```

In various components I want to animate the progress bar (like e.g. Youtube) with `this.$loadingBar.start()`.

---

My plugin consists of a plugin JavaScript file...

```
import LoadingBar from './LoadingBar.vue';

const vueLoadingBar = {
  install () { 
    const loadingBarModule = {
      start () {
        // Start animating by setting the computed `progress` variable in the component, for simple
        // demonstration with setInterval
        setInterval(() => { 
          // How do I set `progress` that updates the component. Or is there an even better way to solve this?
        }, 500);
      }
    }

    Vue.component('vue-loading-bar', LoadingBar);

    Vue.prototype.$loadingBar = loadingBarModule;
  }
}

export default vueLoadingBar;
```

...and a `.vue` file

```
<template>
  <div class="c-loading-bar" :style="style"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      style () {
        return {
          transform: `translateX(${this.progress}%)`,
        }
      },
      progress() {
        return 0;
      }
      /* other computed data */
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .c-loading-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    height: 5px;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

What's the best way to "control" the LoadingBar component from within the plugin (e.g. this.$loadingBar.start())?

Comment: Why not do a simple loader component and do a progress prop to control it? If you really want to stick with plugin you can receive prop for progress and fire some events for completed / started

Comment: @AfikDeri I will only include the component once in my application but I want to control (start the loading animation) on various parts of my application (e.g. AJAX, routing, in some other cases). Since I don't want to include a new component every time I'm loading something, I'd need some kind of global "function" (thus why I thought I need `this.$loadingBar`). How would you receive the prop for progress and fire events in a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested: In the end, I gave my component a data `name`

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'UNIQUE_NAME',
    };
  }
}
```

and added the following code to my plugin `install` function

```
Vue.mixin({
  created() {
    if (this.name === 'UNIQUE_NAME') {
      console.log('You can now access the component with', this);
    }
  },
});
```